# neo4j migration in laravel doesnot work properly

Tags: laravel, neo4j, neoeloquent

I am using Neo4j in my application with /Vinelab/NeoEloquent. Now the problem is that when I run  php artisan `neo4j:migrate --database=neo4j`
 , node for the migration table is created.

Not any labels defined in function up() is not created. What should I do to solve this?

Schema class is,

```
<?php
use Vinelab\NeoEloquent\Schema\Blueprint;
use Vinelab\NeoEloquent\Migrations\Migration;
class CreateTestpostsTable extends Migration {
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Neo4jSchema::label('Testposts', function(Blueprint $label)
    {
          $label->unique('tpid');
          $label->index('name');
          $label->index('content');
    });
}
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Neo4jSchema::drop('Testposts');   
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your issue was not very clear because of double "not" in the sentence. Please check out if I edited correctly.

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the problem you have?

Comment: @Yakovl thanks for your replay

Comment: Can you please provide the code in your Schema class?

Comment: @Mulkave My schema class is provided.I am beginner and i am not sure about things in neo4j

Answer (score 0):

According to your Schema code, no labels should be expected to be created. You are setting a constraint on the `tpid` to be unique, and indexing the `name` and `content` of the nodes with `Testposts` label.

To check if your migration has taken effect:

- Try creating two nodes with the same `tpid` and you should get an error
- Try profiling the queries to the `name` and `content` properties, this link should help with that: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypherdoc-basic-query-tuning-example.html

On a side note, if the Label of the node in your model is `Post` or anything other than `Testposts`, then you should change `Testposts` to whatever is in your model for this to work properly.

Comment: may I ask you to have a look at a NeoEloquent related question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76598569/cannot-use-neo4j-with-laravel-with-the-help-of-neoeloquent ?