# Cannot use Neo4j with Laravel with the help of NeoEloquent

Tags: php, laravel, neo4j, neoeloquent

I am trying to use [Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/) database in a Laravel project using [NeoEloquent](https://github.com/Vinelab/NeoEloquent) driver. I followed the instructions there. The `config/database.php` file has:

```
'default' => 'neo4j',

    'connections' => [

        'neo4j' => [
        'driver' => 'neo4j',
        'host'   => 'localhost',
        'port'   => 7687,
        'username' => 'neo4j',
        'password' => 'neo4j',
    ],
      .........
]
```

In `web.php`, I have:

```
Route::get('/save/country', [CountryController::class,'store'])->name('save_country');
```

`Country.php` model file has:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use NeoEloquent;

// class Country extends Model
class Country extends NeoEloquent 
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
      'country'
    ];


   
}
```

In `CountryController.php`, I have -

public function store(StoreCountryRequest $request)
{

```
$country_info = new Country();
$country_info->country='India';
$relation = $country_info->save();

echo 'Success';
```

}

When I hit the URL `save/country`, I get the Exception:

RuntimeException
Cannot connect to any server on alias: default with Uris: ('bolt://localhost:7687')

What is the thing that I am doing wrong ? How to make the problem go away ?

**EDIT:** I am using Neo4j Desktop app from [here](https://neo4j.com/download/).

Comment: Is your database running? Are you able to connect from outside Laravel?

Comment: @apokryfos, What do you mean by connecting from outside ?

Comment: @apokryfos, I have a created a Project named `tweety` in neo4j desktop app. Under it, I have tweetyDBMS. Then under it , I have neo4j and tweetdb. I clicked on  the tweetyDBMS to start it. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use post and put to store and update data, get is only used when you pull data from a database.

Update your code
Route::get('/save/country', [CountryController::class,'store'])->name('save_country');

to store
Route::post('/save/country', [CountryController::class,'store'])->name('save_country');
and to update
Route::put('/update/country', [CountryController::class,'update'])->name('update_country');

Regarding the Neo4j driver exception, though I am not an expert in Neo4j, you can check and try the following things:

- What is your development environment?
- Check if port 7687 is open and available or not.
- If you are using or installing multiple Apache servers for development, then close or shut down the other Apache server.

Check this link to get more about Neo4j:
https://www.graphable.ai/resource/bolt-localhost-7687/

Comment: that does not work.